# How to export Sikuli scripts to java?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, automated-tests, sikuli

I am new to automation and have to use Sikuli, can you all tell me how to export Sikuli script in java also is it possible to integrate those scripts with Selenium....

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: If you have existing Sikuli scripts already, makes more sense to use Selenium in Python/Jython to make the integration easier.

Answer (score 1):

"export" scripts to Java is not possible in this sense, since Sikuli scripts are written in Python scripting language and the scripts itself are run using the Jython interpreter (Java base implementation of Python language).

But since the the essential Sikuli features are implemented using Java, you might transcript/translate a script to Java code, since the Sikuli functions are nearly identical on the Python API level and the Java API level.

But if you have more complex Sikuli Scripts, that you want to run from Java code, there are  options to do that:

- run the script like from command line, but in a subprocess
- run the script using Sikuli's ScriptRunner